# Func won't stop running

Tags: ios, swift

I have the below code whereby the `captureOutput` function won't stop running. Due to this, the `prepare(for segue)` function isn't being executed either.

Here is my console output:

> 2017-07-14 13:15:50.142147 [9101:1993811] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   7
>   fatal error: Index out of range (lldb)

Comment: Why have you edited the question to remove all of the code? It is now meaningless

Comment: @ Annabelle Sykes Did the below solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually stop running the capturesession that you have established earlier. A sample code is shown below -

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {

                print(objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue)
                captureSession?.stopRunning()
                scannedCode= metadataObj.stringValue

                // call the below line in the main thread once your background process is done above
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Seguename", sender: self)

            }
```

Once you have got the result from your barcode scan in any of the if statements and you are sure your scan is complete, you will have to stop the capture session. I have assumed that your metadatobj has a non nil string value and then stopped the capturesession in the example.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are capturing some media so it will continuously capture data to you. 
Once metadata not captured, `metadataObjects[0]` leading to crash.

check `metadataObjects.count` before use `metadataObjects[0]`!